# Get current username of a IP address which is connected with network

Tags: c#, networking

100+ systems connected through the network. I want to get the current username of a particular system from windows server. For example, I want to know which user currently logged in a particular system(192.168.1.2).How to achieve this?

Comment: I doubt a system would give you such data, except if you've some known app running in all those system which would answer your call and has the option to tell you it.

Comment: There is no correlation between IP address and Windows username. Any user can log in to 192.168.1.2 as long as they have a local account or an AD account.

Comment: Can't we get the detail from Server's AD?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977602/how-to-find-network-machine-names-and-the-user-logged-in-that-machine)

Comment: No, that would not be a great solution, because there could be mulitple users logged in at the same time.

Comment: Or even: http://superuser.com/questions/144685/how-to-find-username-on-remote-computer

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: If your "server" is exposing a WCF service, it would be as simple as to enable Windows Security for your WCF endpoint. Then the user name would be readily available.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following DOS Command using C# (`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`)

```
  nbtstat –a ipaddress
```

This will give the computer name

```
  net view /domain:ad > somefile.txt
```

Where *ad* is the name of the domain you want to search and somefile.txt is the name of the file to contain the output.

In the somefile.txt you can find the username besides ip address

I hope using this info you can get the solution

Comment: I want check which user currently using this system(192.168.1.2) at every minute and display it in a label.

Comment: you can derive the solution from my answer !

Comment: Can't we get that directly? Because I don't know how to use the above code.!

Comment: You first try this in command prompt in the server in which you are going to monitor then using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start you can run the command in c# without using command prompt then all you have to do is ...run the command so we'll get a text file and parse the text file to get the name that's it

Comment: 'nbtstat –a ipaddress' this is not giving the username.  The second one giving error.

Comment: Can you give me the code that you worked ? and what was the error now ?

Comment: you have to try this in windows server machine !

Comment: @SarathJasrin -  Did you try ?