# How to get the all computers list connected to network?

Tags: c#, windows, networking, tcp

How do I get a list of all the IP addresses (and possibly computer names?) in use on the same subnet as my machine using C#?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105676/get-a-list-of-all-computers-on-a-network-w-o-dns

Comment: What do you mean by 'all computers'? You could try broadcast-pinging the entire subnet, but that would only give you computers that respond to ping.. you could try connecting to them via windows shares..

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ListNetworkComputers.aspx

Comment: can you please tell me how to access the IP address of computers connected into the network